# Deleting Amazon S3 directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, carrierwave

I'm trying to delete an Amazon S3 directory after executing the destroy action on my controller.

controllers\videos_controller.rb:

```
def destroy
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  @video.destroy
  redirect_to videos_path, notice:  "The video #{@video.name} has been deleted."
end
```

models\video.rb:

```
after_destroy :remove_S3_directory

def remove_S3_directory
  path_to_be_deleted = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/video/attachment/(ID of the video)"
  FileUtils.remove_dir(path_to_be_deleted, :force => true)
end
```

How can I specify a path_to_be_deleted without hardcoding the path?

Comment: which field is containing video ?

Comment: @ShamsulHaque - "attachment" is the field that actually has the video file.  Currently, my videos are stored at "http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/uploads/video/attachment/1", with "1" being the unique id of the video in the db.  I need to delete the directory that the video resides in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing Amazon's aws-sdk gem (carrierwave-sdk gem will also work in lieu of aws-sdk) and the using AWS delete_all method to remove all files based on a prefix.  The format to use this method is as follows:

```
s3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects.with_prefix('uploads/video/attachment/1/').delete_all
```

Thus, I've put the following code in my controller:

```
def destroy
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])

  # Manipulating the string that points to the path under "bucket"
  directory_to_be_deleted = File.dirname(@video.attachment.url)
  bucket = ENV['AWS_BUCKET'] + '/'
  directory_to_be_deleted = directory_to_be_deleted.split(bucket)[1]
  directory_to_be_deleted = directory_to_be_deleted + '/'

  # Use Amazon APIs to remove directory
  s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_KEY_VALUE'])
  s3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects.with_prefix(directory_to_be_deleted).delete_all

  @video.destroy
  redirect_to videos_path, notice:  "The video #{@video.name} has been deleted."
end
```

I suppose most of this code belongs in the model instead of the controller but it works so for now, I'm going to keep it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:-

In controllers\videos_controller.rb:

```
def destroy
  @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  vid = @video
  @video.destroy
  path_to_be_deleted = vid.attachment
  FileUtils.remove_dir(path_to_be_deleted, :force => true)
  redirect_to videos_path, notice:  "The video #{vid.name} has been deleted."
end
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but this didn't work.  One of the files was deleted but the directory remained intact.  Does the folder have to be empty in order to be deleted?

Comment: just deleted all files within the S3 directory first before calling the destroy action in the controller but didn't make a difference; the directory on Amazon was not deleted.

Comment: what do you mean by `Does the folder have to be empty in order to be deleted?`

Comment: The directory in which the video attachment is stored also contains a thumbnail image (of the video).  I was wondering if the video and thumbnail need to be deleted first prior to deleting the directory.  Based on my 2nd comment above, it seems that the directory does not have to be empty before being deleted.

Comment: Before deleting any directory in s3 you should delete all the directory which are contained in the directory that you want to delete

Comment: There are no nested directories within "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/video/attachment/1".  Only files are contained within the /1.  Even if I hardcode path_to_be_deleted = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/video/attachment/1", the directory, empty or not, does not get deleted.  Also, if I remove the ":force => true" option, I get an "Invalid argument - https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/video/attachment/1" error. So maybe the question is: can I use FileUtils.remove_dir to remove material on Amazon S3?